# Формат даты при записи в БД

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Запрос выглядит так:

```
queryMysql("INSERT INTO tasks (deadline) VALUES(DATE_FORMAT('$deadline', '%d.%m.%Y'));
```

Но почему-то `DATE_FORMAT` игнорируется и 03.05.2016 записывается в бд как 2020-05-20, как исправить?

Comment: А тип поля какой? Если не строка, то ничего удивительного. (btw вижу у вас тут sqlInjection)

Comment: Тип поля date, с ним никак не выйдет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `date` хранит так, как ей [БД] удобнее.
Если хочешь, чтобы было удобнее тебе, то бери строку.

Comment: Поменяла. Тут еще чудеса начинаются: при вводе с DATE_FORMAT 15.03.2001 превращается в 20.01.2015, а при выводе, опять же с DATE_FORMAT, в 20.05.2020

Comment: Где-то, видимо, сбиты настройки времени сервера...

Comment: А зачем вы вообще делаете DATE_FORMAT при insert?

Comment: Вот что скажу - храните время в TIMESTAMP, а форматируйте на языке, который оперирует с БД. Это очень удобно и практично.

Comment: потому что при формате поля date дата записывалась неправильно, я думала дело в формате. при формате поля varchar и без DATE_FORMAT все проблемы исчезли, спасибо
(Правда теперь некорректно работает сравнение текущей даты и даты из бд >_> но это уже другая история)

Comment: @tanias08, перепиши сортировку, да и `ORDER BY` никто не отменял :)

Comment: Так ORDER BY и было.

Подвожу итог: при форматах даты TIMESTAMP и DATE некорректно сохраняется дата в формате "дд.мм.гггг" в бд при вводе.  
При формате VARCHAR все сохраняется и отображается корректно, но не работает сортировка ORDER BY (сортирует по дд. и успокаивается)

Comment: Работает он, просто нужно условие правильно составить.

Comment: Как правильно составить условие в ORDER BY? Там параметров кроме от меньшего к большему или наоборот нету